# Как сделать взаимодействие программы (python) с exel или word файлом?

Tags: python

Хочу реализовать программу, которая с помощью виджетов сможет взаимодействовать с эксэль или ворд файлом (например, написал текст в окне программы, он отобразился в какой-нибудь ячейке эксель и тд), а в конечном итоги по нажатию клавиши печатать этот файл. Возможно ли такое реализовать, если да, то какие библиотеки это позволят сделать? Я так понимаю, с tkinter или customtkinter не получится.

Comment: tkinter или customtkinter - это всего-навсего библиотеки для создания интерфейса программы и в целом они вполне себе подойдут для вашей задачи. Вам нужно для начала декомпозировать вашу заду, сперва попробуйте чтото записать в exel, затем попробуйте отправить документ на печать и только тогда уже собирайте все вместе с интерфейсом. Но если вам нужно чтото готовое, то в Qt можно печатать через виджеты например и если ничего не путаю то и с exel можно работать.

Comment: @Amgarak то есть попробовать сначала без графического интерфейса это сделать, а потом уже пытаться привязать это все к виджетам, так?

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам небольшой пример:

```
import openpyxl
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit, QDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QFileDialog
from PyQt6.QtPrintSupport import QPrintDialog, QPrinter


def print_selected_text(editor, printer):
    dialog = QPrintDialog(printer)

    if editor.textCursor().hasSelection():
        dialog.addEnabledOption(QPrintDialog.PrintDialogOption.PrintSelection)

    if dialog.exec() == QDialog.DialogCode.Accepted:
        editor.print(printer)

def save_to_excel(text):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws['A1'] = text
    wb.save("output.xlsx")

def choose_file_and_print(editor, printer):
    file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, None, None, "Excel Files (*.xlsx)")
    if file_path:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
        ws = wb.active
        text = ""
        for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):
            text += '\t'.join(str(cell) for cell in row) + '\n'
        editor.setPlainText(text)
        print_selected_text(editor, printer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    printer = QPrinter()

    main_window = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(main_window)

    editor = QTextEdit()

    print_button = QPushButton("Напечатать текст с формы")
    print_button.clicked.connect(lambda: print_selected_text(editor, printer))

    save_button = QPushButton("Сохранить в Excel")
    save_button.clicked.connect(lambda: save_to_excel(editor.toPlainText()))

    choose_file_button = QPushButton("Выбрать exel файл для печати")
    choose_file_button.clicked.connect(lambda: choose_file_and_print(editor, printer))

    layout.addWidget(editor)
    layout.addWidget(print_button)
    layout.addWidget(save_button)
    layout.addWidget(choose_file_button)

    main_window.setLayout(layout)
    main_window.show()

    app.exec()
```

Интерфейс и печать через `PyQt6`, а работа с `exel` через `openpyxl`.
Разумеется это лишь демонстрационный пример и его нужно доработать.

[Пример печати отсюда](https://runebook.dev/ru/docs/qt/qtprintsupport-index)

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться на данном примере!

Comment: @ВадимЛорейнченко Если ответ вам помог, не забудьте его принять.